# Mail:(); php not working in message

Tags: php, email

So basicly I have been working on getting an confermational email set up so they can click on the link and it will activate there account i got all that working what i need help with is that I want the link to work but its not changing any of the php thats in this link

> http://www.pigigram.com/emailconfirm.php?username=$un&code=$cc

the $un is pulling out of the registration form to get the username and the $cc is a randomly generated numbers that is change to 0 when registration is activated. And i want it to work in the html format that is displayed in the email that is sent below.

> The message is removed below due to the nature is was to many characters but heres a preview link https://www.pigigram.com/email

The confirm email link is the only one im worried about for it to be working and i cut out the snipit of what exactly the code is for the button for it to work.

```
$headers = array (
  'From: no-reply@pigigram.com',
  'Content-Type: text/html'
);
$message ='<a style="display: inline-block;text-decoration: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;text-align: center;background-color: #C7702E;color: #ffffff" href="http://www.pigigram.com/emailconfirm.php?username=$un&amp;code=$cc" target="_blank">
                    <span style="font-family:Arial, " helvetica="" neue",="" helvetica,="" sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:32px;"=""><span style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 28px;" data-mce-style="font-size: 14px;">Confirm Email</span></span>
              </a>';
mail($em,'Pigigram Confirmation Email', $message, implode("\n", $headers));
```

> I know when it emails its in html format but is there a way around it where i can run php in it to make the email work towards the user that is created

Comment: You're not printing the content of the values... just the value names. Try: `?username=' . $un . '&code=' . $cc . '`

Comment: PHP variables aren't interpolated into a single-quoted string. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: @iainn luckily variables are not `interpolated` at all :)

Comment: That's a fair point. No idea why that was the word that came to mind. Expanded was what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$link = "http://www.pigigram.com/emailconfirm.php?username=".$un."&code=".$cc;

$message ='<a style="display: inline-block;text-decoration: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;text-align: center;background-color: #C7702E;color: #ffffff" href="'.$link.'" target="_blank">
                    <span style="font-family:Arial, " helvetica="" neue",="" helvetica,="" sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:32px;"=""><span style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 28px;" data-mce-style="font-size: 14px;">Confirm Email</span></span>
              </a>';
```

that was painful lol. Let me know if that fixed it for you!

Answer (score 1):

You're currently printing $un and $cc as text(strings). What you want to do is echo the content of your variables as such:

```
$message ='<a style="display: inline-block;text-decoration: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;text-align: center;background-color: #C7702E;color: #ffffff" href="http://www.pigigram.com/emailconfirm.php?username='.$un.'&amp;code='.$cc.'" target="_blank">
                    <span style="font-family:Arial, " helvetica="" neue",="" helvetica,="" sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:32px;"=""><span style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 28px;" data-mce-style="font-size: 14px;">Confirm Email</span></span>
              </a>';
```

note the escaping of the `$message` string for the two variables